# Opera singing 101

Tags: theory, voice, opera

I like to go to the opera, but I never had the chance of learning the theory behind its music and singing, and I have quite some difficulty to understand whether someone sang well or not. Do you have any resource (book, lecture, video, podcast, ...) which could help me to get a more methodical approach? I am fluent in English, Italian and German.

Thanks!

Comment: You could easily search online for any of the myriad of books on opera, depending on what type of opera you like - loosely you have baroque, classical, romantic, 20th century, and current.  As to whether someone sang well, if you were moved and/or engaged, then for you they sang well.